# How to create global state with React Hooks [TypeScript]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Currently I am trying to make a global state in React Hooks but encounter a problem.

I just created a Provider in Store.tsx and tried with useContext to get the state in other component. But when I type in input with onChange handler there is no state updated? How does that come.

```js
// App.tsx
export const App: FC = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(Context);
  console.log(state.todoList);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const getValue = (target: string) => {
    setInputValue(target);
  };

  const addTodo = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "addTodo", payload: inputValue });
    setInputValue("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => getValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={addTodo}>
        Add Todo
      </button>
      <TodoList />
      {state.value}
    </>
  );
};


// Store.tsx
export const Store: FC = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  console.log(state);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      <App />
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export const Context = createContext<[IStateTypes, Dispatch<any>]>([initialState, () => { }]);
```

[Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/chiholiu10/poker-game-react-hooks?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make some changes in your code. Your action is not being dispatched to the reducer.

```
export const Context = createContext<[IStateTypes, Dispatch<any>]>([
  initialState,
  () => {}
]);

export const Store: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>{children}</Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

With this you make your context available inside of all your child components wrapped by that context. Then you need to apply it in your index.js.

```
import { Store } from "./Store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Store>
      <App />
    </Store>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That happened coz ur  component located and initialized in index.tsx, but you trying to wrap it inside store.tsx, so ur context is empty, for now ur application inside index.ts looks like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

you should write it this way:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      <App />
    </Context.Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```